# windows 7 64 bits incorrect PATH when loading 32 bits library for 32 bits exe

Tags: windows-7, path, 32bit-64bit

I have an exe which depends on libeay32.dll. Both compiled for 32 bits.

I have copied the exe to C:\Program files (x86)\app\bin and the dll to C:\Program files (x86)\app\lib.
To ensure the correct working, i have added C:\Program files (x86)\app\lib to the path.

On Windows 7 64 bits, when i execute the exe, i got a libeay32.dll not found error.

Using dependency walker for 32 bits, the library is properly located at C:\Program files (x86)\app\lib.
Using sysinternal process explorer the app is executed properly.
Using cmd also works.
Using dependency walker for 64 bits, i can see the missing libraries.
Copying the two files toghether or dll to syswow64 also works perfectly.

If the application was compiled for 32 bits...

Why isnt windows looking for 32 bits libraries?
Why arent the libraries resolved if directory is already on path?

My guess is that w7 is ignoring the path, but according to this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
it shouldnt!.

Why i cant run my exe with dependencies located on path?
Should i register the library or something?

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The program its correctly launched/executed when done from start menu->program, but not directly on the .exe...wtf?

Using procmon seems to be trying to open (note the lack of " "):
  "C:\Program Files(x86)\myapp\Third-Party\openssl\LIBEAY32.dll"
but in the path its correct (rechecked: "C:\Program Files (x86)\myapp\Third-Party\openssl")

ANSWER?:
is there a know scenario/bug where setting **"C:\Program Files (x86)" on path, lead windows try to load "C:\Program Files(x86)" instead**????(see using procmon without ANY filter)

Windows 7 x64 bug?

Comment: As far as I know, PATH is consulted only to locate an EXECUTABLE. A Lib or DLL cannot execute on its own - can only support another executable.

Comment: @Arun - Windows does use the path to locate DLL's.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx

Comment: My bad, I take back. Yes it does. Thank you very much for correcting my mistake!

Comment: Instead of copying the file, you should register the file libeay32.dll using regsvr(32). I assume Windows will automatically load the library.

Comment: @Nick Binnet - That doenst work either. I tried both regsrv32 on syswow64 and system32.

Do you know if theres a registry key, other than HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\KnownDLLs for 32 and 64 enviroments, like Wow6432Node ?

Comment: @Nick regsvr32 is for COM registration - unless the dll is a COM component that exports `DllRegisterServer` and `DllUnregisterServer` this will just fail.

Comment: How did you add the `lib` folder to the path?  You might want to try using `%programfiles%\app\lib`, which should automatically get expanded to the required path for a 32 bit process.

Comment: @Justin - Both, the "%programfiles(x86)" or "C:\Program Files (x86)" are added to the path without problems, but when the exe is invoked, i can see its tring to open "C:\Program Files(x86)"

Comment: Looks like there is something up with the path expansion - have you tried just `%programfiles%` (no (x86) bit)?

Comment: @Justin - As the problem is on windows 7 x64, i havent tried that...but i dont think thats the problem, as other variables have %windir% and are also working/tried before mines.

Answer (score 0):

You can mvoe the lib into the same directory, because there it always checks first. If its found, it is used. 
On Windows 64 bit systems you can (not tried) also move the libs to the SystemWOW64 folder where the 32bit versions are stored, but I would recommend the first version.